# Cython, remove numpy dependency in setup.py

Tags: numpy, cython, setuptools, distutils

In order to build a Cython extension using numpy, one has to add `numpy.get_include()` in "setup.py":

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    ...
    include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Otherwise, one gets this error:

```
fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
```

even if one builds the Extension directly from the precompiled .c file.

The obvious solution is to install numpy beforehand.

But `setup.py install` to install a package is the usual way to install all the package dependencies (including numpy). Is there any way to get rid of the dependency to numpy when distributing the package, i.e. so that people don't have to install numpy before running `setup.py install` ?

I was thinking about including the numpy .h files into the distribution, but I am afraid of version clashes with an existing numpy version of the user.

Maybe try to import, and if I get an `ImportError`, include the packaged .h files? Any standard/simpler way?

**Edit:** or is there any way to force the installation of numpy before `setup()` runs?

Comment: (May not be what you're looking for but) if you write your Cython extension using memoryviews, rather than `ndarray`s, you don't need a dependency on numpy headers.

Comment: @DavidW thanks! I used to write memoryviews but was told that is was unnecessary. That is a good argument to put them pack.

Comment: It works, but memoryviews can't be pickled for multiprocessing and need to be cast back to ndarray (with an overhead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be ugly but I did this to force the install/upgrade:

```
from pkg_resources import parse_version

## Install numpy if it is not found or too old
try:
    import numpy
    if parse_version(numpy.__version__) < parse_version('1.10'):
        print("numpy {} was found but is too old. Upgrading.".format(numpy.__version__))
        raise ImportError
    print("Numpy was found. Build extensions.")
except ImportError:
    print("Building Cython extensions requires numpy. Installing numpy.")
    import pip
    pip_args = ['install', numpy_req]
    pip.main(pip_args)
    import numpy
```